# What is the Java equivalent of $var?

Tags: java, enums

I'm new to Java and had a newbie question. I am trying to randomly retrieve an enum value as below.

```
public enum ParkedCar {
     car1(....),
     car2(....);
......
}

Random rand = new Random();
int i = 1 + rand.nextInt(5);
String s = "car" + i;
ParkedCar car = ParkedCar.$s;
```

However, unlike in Perl where we can use $s to insert the value of s, $s is not valid in Java. What is the Java equivalent if one exists?

Thanks!

Comment: ParkerCard.values() will give you array. You may get i-th value of the array.

Comment: Do you mean the car members are not fixed ? It's impossible to implement in Java. The Enum members must be predefined.

Comment: Thanks @kkkkk! ParkedCar.values()[i] worked for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert from enum ordinal to enum type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609860/convert-from-enum-ordinal-to-enum-type)

Answer (score 4):

You want [`Enum.valueOf(String s)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
String s = "car" + i;
ParkedCar car = ParkedCar.valueOf(s);
```

This looks up the enum instance by its name.

Note that if a matching instance isn't found this method will throw a [`IllegalArgumentException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html)

Answer (score 0):

Java is very different than Perl.

You can't build a variable name with a string and then reference it.

(*You actually can do it with reflection, but that makes **zero** sense here*)

You can get a random enum value like this:

```
Random rand = new Random();
ParkedCar[] carArray = ParkedCar.values();
int index = rand.nextInt(carArray.length);
ParkedCar randomCar = carArray[index];
```

Answer (score 0):

try: ParkedCar c=ParkedCar.values()[new Random().nextInt(ParkedCar.values().length)];