# JAVA: returning enumerated object name by the ordinal value

Tags: java, enums

How do I return the name value of enumerated object by its specific ordinal number?

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*

public class Enumarating {
      enum Animals {bunneh , sheep , horse , cow , supercow}

      public static void main(String [] args) {
          Random rand = new Random();
          Animals animal;
      }
}
```

I will define the random range to 4, and let's say I get number 2. Then I want "horse" to be printed.
What method should I use?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/609860/2580773

Comment: You want http://stackoverflow.com/a/19277247/785663

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is:

```
Animals.values()[rand.nextInt(Animals.values().length)];
```

**[edit]**

```
Animals.values() // gets an array with all the enum constants
rand.nextInt(x) // returns a random integer between 0 (inclusinve) and x (exclusive)
```

Comment: can u explain abit what u did there in the brackets?

Answer (score 0):

```
Animals values[] = Animals.values()
```

This will give you your value:-

```
values[rand.nextInt(your_range)]
```