# How can I get a enum member by the ordinal value in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I know I can get the ordinal value of a enum member using the code `Color.BLUE.ordinal`.

Now I hope to get Color.Green when I know the ordinal value of a enum member, how can I do?

**Code**

```
enum class Color{
    RED,BLACK,BLUE,GREEN,WHITE
}



var aOrdinal=Color.BLUE.ordinal //it's 2

val bOrdinal=3  //How can I get Color.Green
```

Comment: Same approach works as in java. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609860/convert-from-enum-ordinal-to-enum-type

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just use `values()` function which will return the Array of enum values and use ordinal as an index

**Example**

```
val bOrdinal=3

val yourColor : Color = Color.values()[bOrdinal]
```

Answer (score 14):

Safety first:

```
// Default to null
val color1: Color? = Color.values().getOrNull(bOrdinal)

// Default to a value
val color2: Color = Color.values().getOrElse(bOrdinal) { Color.RED }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Kotlin `enumValues<>()` to get it

Example

```
    enum class Color{
    GREEN,YELLOW
}

fun main(str:Array<String>){
    val c  = enumValues<Color>()[1]
   print("Color name is ${c.name} and ordinal is ${c.ordinal}")
}
```

Prints "Color name is YELLOW and ordinal is 1"

Answer (score 1):

As

> 'Enum.values()' is recommended to be replaced by 'Enum.entries' since 1.9

use:

```
val bOrdinal = 3
val yourColor = Color.entries[bOrdinal]
```