# How to resolve java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant error?

Tags: java, sql, enums

I try to write mothod that extract all the coupon list from db.
this is the method:

```
public ArrayList<Coupon> getAllCoupons() {
        Connection connection = null;
        ArrayList<Coupon> coupons = new ArrayList<Coupon>();
        PreparedStatement statement = null;
        ResultSet result = null;
        Coupon coupon = new Coupon();
        try {
            connection = ConnectionPool.getInstance().getConnection();
            String sqlStatement = "select * from coupons";
            statement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlStatement);
            result = statement.executeQuery();
            while (result.next()) {
                System.out.println("result arrived");
                coupon = extractCouponFromResult(result);
                coupons.add(coupon);
                System.out.println(coupon);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                // closing all resources
                ConnectionPool.closeResources(statement);
            }
        }
        return coupons;

    }
```

Another method gets the results and organizes everything in the array:

```
public static Coupon extractCouponFromResult(ResultSet result) {
        Coupon coupon = null;
        try {
            // extract the data from db to coupon object
            coupon = new Coupon();
            coupon.setId(result.getInt("id"));
            coupon.setCompanyId(result.getInt("company_id"));
//          coupon.setCategory(Category.valueOf(result.getString(3)));a
            coupon.setCategory(Category.valueOf(result.getString("CATEGORY_ID").toUpperCase()));
            coupon.setTitle(result.getString("title"));
            coupon.setDescription(result.getString("description"));
            coupon.setStartDate(result.getDate("start_date"));
            coupon.setEndDate(result.getDate("end_date"));
            coupon.setAmount(result.getInt("amount"));
            coupon.setPrice(result.getDouble("price"));
            coupon.setImage(result.getString("image"));
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return coupon;

    }
```

I get this error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.chana.coupons.beans.Category.3
Coupon [id=14, companyId=3, category=null, title=null, description=null, startDate=null, endDate=null, amount=0, price=0.0, image=null]
result arrived
Coupon [id=15, companyId=3, category=null, title=null, description=null, startDate=null, endDate=null, amount=0, price=0.0, image=null]
result arrived
Coupon [id=16, companyId=3, category=null, title=null, description=null, startDate=null, endDate=null, amount=0, price=0.0, image=null]
result arrived
.....

my enum class is:

```
package com.chana.coupons.beans;

public enum Category {
    FOOD(1), ELECTRICITY(2), RESTAURANT(3),VACATION(4);

    private int id;
    private Category(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public int getId() {
         return id;
    }
    public int getId(Category category) {
        
         return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id,Category category ) {
        
        this.id = id;
    }
    public static Category fromString(String string) {
        for (Category c : Category.values()) {
            if(c.equals(string)) {
                return c;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

In the database everything appears according to the enum.

I would be happy for help on how to resolve this

Comment: How are the categories stored in category_id, as ordinal values or as enum names ? In the first case, see here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609860/convert-from-enum-ordinal-to-enum-type

Comment: the categories stored in category_id as enum names

Comment: Are you using Custom Convertor to perform the transformation? If not please look at section 4 (Using JPA 2.1 @Converter Annotation) from https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-persisting-enums-in-jpa

Comment: Yet the error message seems to look for an enum constant called `3` : `No enum constant com.chana.coupons.beans.Category.3`.

Comment: resolved :) 
the problem were in the sql statement. it should be with join with other table. the statement: "select coupons.*, categories.name from coupons left join categories on coupons.category_id = categories.id"; 
thank everybody!